# How to read array's element inside print function in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, f-string

I want to create following output **using print function only once:**

```
1 - Add
2 - Subtract
3 - Divide
4 - Multiply
```

To do this I am using following piece of code:

```
> for i in range(1, 5):
>     array = ["Add", "Subtract", "Divide", "Multiply"]
>     print(f"{i} - array[{i-1}]")
```

But the output I get is:

```
1 - array[0]
2 - array[1]
3 - array[2]
4 - array[3]
```

Could you help me what am I doing wrong?
How can I call element of the array inside print function?

Answer (score 3):

You need to move list indexing inside the `{}`, otherwise `array` will be interpreted as a string:

```
print(f"{i} - {array[i-1]}")
```

But you are using the `print` function 4 times in your loop. If, as you say, you wish to use `print` only once, you can unpack a generator expression and use the `sep` argument:

```
array = ['Add', 'Subtract', 'Divide', 'Multiply']
print(*(f'{idx} - {val}' for idx, val in enumerate(array, 1)), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is :

```
print(f"{i} - {array[i-1]}")
```

But it's always better that you initialize array before loop or else you are creating the same array everytime you run the loop.

So, something like this is more efficient:

```
array = ["Add", "Subtract", "Divide", "Multiply"]
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(f"{i} - {array[i-1]}")

# 1 - Add
# 2 - Subtract                                                
# 3 - Divide                                                 
# 4 - Multiply
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the array variable captured as well: `print(f"{i} - {array[i-1]}")`

Answer (score 0):

It can be changed to this:

```
print(i, '-', array[i-1])
```

If you use format, only be interpreted in curly braces `{}`, the outer `array` is treated as a string, so you can make it work like this:

```
 print(f"{i} - {array[i-1]}")
```